# Fancybox not playing HTML5 video... can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm attempting to get Fancybox to auto open up and auto-play a webm video file on page load. It seems like this is something Fancybox should be handling without any issue, but for some reason, I can't get it to work. I was hoping someone could take a look and maybe spot what I'm missing.

This is being done inside of Squarespace, if that makes a difference.

I can get it to work correctly when I use a swf file, like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([{
        href: '/s/phlogo.swf',
        title: 'Logo'
    }], {
        padding: 0,
        afterShow: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fancybox.close();
            }, 15000);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I try to use the webm file instead, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox.open({
        padding: 0,
        content   : '<source src="/s/phlogo.webm" type="video/webm" />',
        type: "html",
        afterShow: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fancybox.close();
            }, 15000);
        }
    });
});
```

It just opens up a tiny, empty fancybox window. The phlogo.swf file is definitely there in the right location, so I know that's not the problem.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've been pulling my hair out on this one for way too long, so any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: not all browsers support webm (atleast ie/safari). which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm trying it in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just targeting browsers that support *webm* file *type*, then you could do

```
$.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    content: "<video><source src='/s/phlogo.webm' type='video/webm' /></video>",
    type: "html", // cause you are using html tags
    afterShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
        }, 15000);
    }
}); // fancybox
```

**Notice** the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) tag is used to specify multiple media resources for the `<video>` tag and cannot be placed alone so this line

```
content   : '<source src="/s/phlogo.webm" type="video/webm" />'
```

...won't work

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dah4uv5n/)**

**NOTE**:

If you want to support a wider variety of browsers and devices, then you may need to use a *player* plugin like [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) (MEJS). Check **[this tutorial](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/)** for how-to use MEJS with fancybox.